# At point $(0,0)$ find partial limit of $f(x,y)=e^{\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+y}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Given $F:X\to R^n (X \subset R^m),$ $A \subset X,$ $a\in A',$ a vector $b\in R^n$ vector is called a partial limit at $a'$ by the set $A,$ denoted by $$b=lim_{x\to a,x\in A}F(x),$$
if $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta>0: \forall x\in A, (0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow|F(x)-b|<\epsilon )$

Now for a concrete example, at point $(0,0)$ I must find the partial limit of $$f(x,y)=e^{\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+y}}}$$

by the set $A=\{(x,x):x>0\}.$

$f(x,x)=e^{\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}}$ intuitively, and because $|x|<\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}},$ the dominant term here in the denominator will be $\sqrt{x}$ so the limit will be $1$.So

$$e^{\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}} \leq e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}\delta}{\sqrt{\frac{\delta^2}{2}+\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}}}}}=e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{0.5+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\delta}}}}$$

here I am thinking taking $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\delta}>\epsilon$ so $\delta=[\sqrt{2}\epsilon+1]$ but in this part I am not sure. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Set,
$$ L = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} e^{\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}} $$
then,
$$ ln L = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+x}} $$
Solve this using L'hopital rule taking derivative of numerator and denominator,
$$ ln L = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2}{0.5 (2x+1) \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}} = \frac{2 \sqrt{x^2+x}}{0.5 * (2x+1)} = 0$$
hence $L = e^0 = 1$

Comment: Thank you I know about this, I just wanted proof using $\epsilon, \delta$ definition.